# Laravel validation - Logic in validation - Only validate a specific field if argument is true

Tags: php, validation, laravel

So if the user has an ability to edit the description, then only should the description field be validated. Otherwise, it should be ignored.

I am currently doing it like so:

```
  public function rules()
    {
        $rules = user()->can('edit-description') ? ['description' => 'max:120'] : null;
        return $rules += [
            'name'     => 'required',
            'avatar'   => 'required|active_url',
            'timezone' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

However, I do think that there is a better way of doing this. How else can I achieve this? I not think this is the best way.

Comment: Seems like a good way to do it to me

Comment: How about this way: `rules['description'] = user()->cannot('edit-description') ?: 'required';`